# Executing echo Command Using Launcher Icon

Tags: launcher, echo

I am controlling the fan speed on my notebook using acpi and the command:

```
echo level n > /proc/acpi/ibm/fan
```

- where `level n` is a number between `1` and `7`.

It works, and after I changed the permissions of the fan file I was able to write to it from a terminal screen.

However, when I create a new launcher to do this from the desktop it doesn't work. The above line is in the 'Command' section and I have set permissions so that the icon is executed as a program but when I double-click on it nothing happens. There are no error messages displayed.

Is there something special about using the `echo` command in a launcher or am I doing this totally wrong?

Comment: Two problems: That command likely needs to be run in a root shell, but the command in a .desktop file is run as your user; a .desktop file doesn't accept shell syntax (`>` is redirection from the shell).

Comment: It's not a permissions problem. I changed the permissions on /proc/acpi/ibm/fan and I can send commands from a standard terminal window (under my user ID) without issue. It MIGHT however be the shell syntax issue that you mentioned and I'd appreciate a solution.

Comment: @UbuntuDarmstadt `/proc` is remounted on each reboot, so the permissions won't stick, they'll have to be modified each time

Comment: It is not a good idea to change permissions. That should be run with `sudo`, like `echo "level n" | sudo tee /proc/acpi/ibm/fan`.

Answer (score 0):

I do this type of things a different way.

1. Create a script `~./local/bin/fan.sh` like this:

   ```
    #!/bin/sh
   echo level 5 > /proc/acpi/ibm/fan
   ```
2. Make it executable

   ```
   chmod +x ~./local/bin/fan.sh
   ```
3. Create a shortcut to this commad:

   ```
   pkexec /home/$USER/.local/bin/fan.sh
   ```

It will ask for a password.

This is for 18.04. In previous versions use `gksu` instead of `pkexec`.

Comment: Ah! Thank you Pilot6,after creating a couple of scripts  this solution worked first time.